# How to display Hour, Minute values from QTimeEdit to corresponding LCD's?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlcdnumber, qtimeedit

I used QTimeEdit to edit time. But when I clicked "ok" the output is HOUR: 16 MINUTE: 8, no matter what number I put in QTimeEdit. Thus, I want to know what function I must add to correct the set time in QTimeEdit.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_EditTime(object):
    def setupUi(self, EditTime):
        EditTime.setObjectName("EditTime")
        EditTime.resize(392, 293)
        EditTime.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(EditTime)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 160, 118, 22))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59)))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
        self.timeEdit.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
        self.timeEdit.setMinimumTime(QtCore.QTime(00, 00, 00))
        self.timeEdit.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.HourSection)
        self.timeEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.OffsetFromUTC)
        self.timeEdit.setTime(QtCore.QTime(24,0,0))
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName("timeEdit")
        self.HourLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
        self.HourLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 111, 51))
        self.HourLCD.setObjectName("HourLCD")
        self.MinuteLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
        self.MinuteLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 111, 51))
        self.MinuteLCD.setObjectName("MinuteLCD")
        self.OK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(EditTime)
        self.OK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 75, 23))
        self.OK.setObjectName("OK")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 46, 31, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(EditTime)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(EditTime)
        self.OK.clicked.connect(self.connect)

    def connect(self):
        self.HourLCD.display(self.timeEdit.HourSection)
        self.MinuteLCD.display(self.timeEdit.MinuteSection)
```

I expect the output base on the QTimeEdit

Answer (score 1):

HourSection and MinuteSection does not represent the time and the minute but the [sections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#Section-enum) of the QTimeEdit. Instead you should get the time using the [time()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#time) method, and using the latter use [hour()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#hour) and [minute()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#minute) to get the hour and the minute, respectively.

Also, you should not modify the code generated by Qt Designer as PyQt indicates, instead you should create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and that uses the initial class as an interface. For more information I recommend reading [this](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code.).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_EditTime(object):
    def setupUi(self, EditTime):
        EditTime.setObjectName("EditTime")
        EditTime.resize(392, 293)
        EditTime.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(EditTime)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 160, 118, 22))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59)))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
        self.timeEdit.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
        self.timeEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
        self.timeEdit.setMinimumTime(QtCore.QTime(00, 00, 00))
        self.timeEdit.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.HourSection)
        self.timeEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.OffsetFromUTC)
        self.timeEdit.setTime(QtCore.QTime(24,0,0))
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName("timeEdit")
        self.HourLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
        self.HourLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 111, 51))
        self.HourLCD.setObjectName("HourLCD")
        self.MinuteLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
        self.MinuteLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 111, 51))
        self.MinuteLCD.setObjectName("MinuteLCD")
        self.OK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(EditTime)
        self.OK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 75, 23))
        self.OK.setObjectName("OK")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 46, 31, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        # self.retranslateUi(EditTime)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(EditTime)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_EditTime):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.OK.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        t = self.timeEdit.time()
        self.HourLCD.display(t.hour())
        self.MinuteLCD.display(t.minute())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a bit slower than eyllanesc and with significant enough differences to post it anyway. Remarks are the same.

Personally I'm more for import statements as advised by PEP docs and for oversight having connections made in their own function.

```py
    import sys, time

    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    class Ui_EditTime(object):

        def setupUi(self, EditTime):
            EditTime.setObjectName("EditTime")
            EditTime.resize(392, 293)
            EditTime.setAutoFillBackground(False)

            self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(EditTime)
            self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 160, 118, 22))
            self.timeEdit.setMaximumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59)))
            self.timeEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
            self.timeEdit.setMinimumDate(QtCore.QDate(1999, 12, 31))
            self.timeEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
            self.timeEdit.setMinimumTime(QtCore.QTime(00, 00, 00))
            self.timeEdit.setCurrentSection(QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.HourSection)
            self.timeEdit.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.OffsetFromUTC)
            self.timeEdit.setTime(QtCore.QTime(24,0,0))
            self.timeEdit.setObjectName("timeEdit")

            self.HourLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
            self.HourLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 111, 51))
            self.HourLCD.setObjectName("HourLCD")

            self.MinuteLCD = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(EditTime)
            self.MinuteLCD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 70, 111, 51))
            self.MinuteLCD.setObjectName("MinuteLCD")

            self.OK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(EditTime)
            self.OK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 75, 23))
            self.OK.setObjectName("OK")

            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 46, 31, 20))
            self.label.setObjectName("label")

            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(EditTime)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 47, 13))
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

            self.retranslateUi(EditTime)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(EditTime)

        def retranslateUi(self, EditTime):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

    class EditTime(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_EditTime):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):

            super(EditTime, self).__init__(parent) # make flexible MainWindow class.

            self.setupUi(self)
            self.connections()   # oversight off all your connections there are made in your application.

        def connections(self):
            self.OK.clicked.connect(self.connect)

        def connect(self):
            t_mod = self.timeEdit.time()
            self.HourLCD.display(t_mod.hour())
            self.MinuteLCD.display(t_mod.minute())

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        print ('Starting QTimeEdit application')
        sys.stdout.flush()   # shows output directly in an editor.


        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = EditTime()
        window.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the substantial difference between your answer and my answer? :-)

Comment: There isn't but if it isn't posted I wasted 15 minutes on fixing this question ;p

Comment: mmm, my question is about the contribution of your answer, IMHO do not see any additional contribution to the community :-)